# Is there a way to make a settings.json simply on a project?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When you want to make a different settings on a specific project, you will make `.vscode/settings.json`.
I know how to make `.vscode/settings.json`. If I make that directory and file and name as `.vscode` and `settings.json` then those files will be functioning as the setting of the project of the directory.

But I'm lazy to do those all acts. Is there some simpler ways to make the `settings.json` file on each project directory? Like by using a shortcut key we could make the file, or just by using a button from a extension.

---updated on Nov 1st, 2022---

I think,

`Select File > Preferences > Settings (or press Ctrl+,)`
and `Select Workspace tab`, and then changing any setting
is the fastest way to make the `.vscode/settings.json` now.
if you change any setting of there, immediately vscode will make the file. No other shortcut, but I think this is quite reasonable.

If you need to change some settings in vscode, vscode will make the `.vscode/settings.json` automatically.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the same thing right now[.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rU13Qbvu_g8) Have you been able to find a solution to this issue? (can you update your post?)

Comment: I updated this article but I don't know you will like this my conclusion

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- go to **Settings UI**, `Ctrl+,`, command **Preferences: Open Settings (UI)**
- select **Workspace** tab
- click **Open Settings (JSON)** button in top right corner

Or

Execute command: **Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)**

---

If you have a **Multi Root Workspace** you can save settings in the `.code-workspace` file or in the `.vscode/settings.json` file for a particular **Folder**

- go to **Settings UI**, `Ctrl+,`, command **Preferences: Open Settings (UI)**
- select **Workspace** tab or use **Folder** drop down
- click **Open Settings (JSON)** button in top right corner

Or

Execute command: **Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)**

Or

Execute command: **Preferences: Open Folder Settings (JSON)**
and select the folder you want to modify the settings for

Comment: In fact, I meant of `Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)`, now I know this. Thanks to your answer, I got to know it.

Comment: @niddddddfier If this solves your question you can mark the answer as the solution

Comment: I would like to, but this is not exact answer so I can't mark this as answer. Can u modify your answer a little bit?

Comment: @niddddddfier It is one `of the other open settings commands`. You would not have found it without this direction, there are many of them how would I know which one you needed, Do I need to list them all?

Comment: I think you don't need to list them all, just some which are related to your words in your answer. Well, even if you will change your answer to just `Execute command: Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)` though, I will mark your answer. Because of your answer I got the great solutions.

Comment: but it would make workspace-level settings and not project-level. Author's question is wrt to a particular project, not the entire workspace.

Comment: @SaurabhKumar what is a project and what is a workspace? For VSC they are the same.

Comment: oops, I misunderstood. Thought user level setting is the same as the workspace level. Gotcha! @rioV8